# What's the encryption type $y$ used in /etc/passwd on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, password, encryption

I know the typical encryption types for Linux are $1$, $2a$, $2y$, $5$, and $6$, but I haven't found any answers for what $y$ is. I'm using the latest version of Kali Linux. The two accounts are dummy accounts made for an exercise.

```
exam_user_1:$y$j9T$Sn7.l9zwy3VX0vbgSX1JQ0$iHN/q4Q9CPnTxm/x01joswdLKgfbexP1BKCkc13pqI6:18845:0:99999:7:::
exam_user_2:$y$j9T$ylZ/f6ILdzB/AFXh3lhRI/$adutx/xXKNf5PmGLUMMfzCa4/uIlS7ZzbU/5LIiPjo3:18845:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Even though the [`shadow(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) says the second field is the "encrypted password", it should be noted that what's actually done to the password there is _hashing_, not encryption. There's no key to decrypt the passwords stored there, the password can only be recovered by trying passwords to see if they match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man 5 crypt`, `AVAILABLE HASHING METHODS`

> ```
> yescrypt
>
>  yescrypt is a scalable passphrase hashing scheme designed by Solar Designer, which is based on Colin Percival's
>  scrypt.  Recommended for new hashes.
>
>  Prefix
>      "$y$"
>
>  Hashed passphrase format
>      \$y\$[./A-Za-z0-9]+\$[./A-Za-z0-9]{,86}\$[./A-Za-z0-9]{43}
>
>  Maximum passphrase length
>      unlimited
>
>  Hash size
>      256 bits
>
>  Salt size
>      up to 512 bits
>
>  CPU time cost parameter
>      1 to 11 (logarithmic)
> ```